# electron-builder cannot find git repository although specifying

Tags: github, windows-10, electron, electron-builder

**package.json**

```
{
    //some other config
    "repository": "git@gitintsrv.domain.com/UserName/RepoName",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "build --win",
        "ship": "build --win -p always"
    }
}
```

**electron-builder.yml**

```
appId: com.xorchat.app.windows
publish:
    provider: github
    token: some_token
```

**electron.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const { autoUpdater } = require("electron-updater");
let win; // this will store the window object

// creates the default window
function createDefaultWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 900, height: 680 });
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/src/index.html`);
    win.on('closed', () => app.quit());
    return win;
}

// when the app is loaded create a BrowserWindow and check for updates
app.on('ready', function() {
    createDefaultWindow()
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
});

// when the update has been downloaded and is ready to be installed, notify the BrowserWindow
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
    win.webContents.send('updateReady')
});

// when receiving a quitAndInstall signal, quit and install the new version ;)
ipcMain.on("quitAndInstall", (event, arg) => {
    autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
})
```

When i am running ***npm run build*** i am receiving this error.

> Error: Cannot detect repository by .git/config. Please specify "repository" in the package.json (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository).
>   Please see https://electron.build/configuration/publish

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably too late, but in case you end up here as I did, here's how I solved it:

Add this to your *package.json*

```
  "build": {
    "publish": [{
       "provider": "github",
       "host": "github.<<DOMAIN>>.com",
       "owner": "<<USER>>",
       "repo": "<<NAME OF YOUR REPO (ONLY THE NAME)>>",
       "token": "<<ACCESS TOKEN>>"
     }]
  }
```

I think the issue is that electron cannot parse corporate github urls, or something.

*********** EDIT:

Make a electron-builder.yml in the root folder, with the following content

```
appId: com.corporate.AppName
publish:
  provider: github
  token: <<ACCESS TOKEN>>
  host: github.corporate.com
  owner: <<User/ Org>>
  repo: <<repo name>>
```

Don't forget to include this file on your .gitignore

Comment: Your `package.json` file will probably be pushed to github repo, so pasting your `token` here isn't the best idea

Answer (score 0):

This use to be a specific issue with Electron Builder 19x, and it has since been fixed:

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2785